# Convert ptr* to ptr* const*

Tags: c++, casting

I currently have this error; 
error C2664: cannot convert parameter 3 from 'ID3D11Buffer *' to 'ID3D11Buffer *const *'

Code line;

```
_deviceContext->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, this->mVertexBuffer.GetBuffer(), &stride, &offset);
```

this->mVertexBuffer.GetBuffer() returns ID3D11Buffer*, a pointer that Im unable to make it fit. Tried a bunch of methods but the answer eludes me, help anyone?

Comment: According to the documentation, it requires a "pointer to an array of vertex buffers". Therefore, if you have one, a pointer to that one is enough. What you're trying to do now is relatable to `void foo(int arr[3]); foo(5);`.

Comment: I guess that makes sense. But still unsure how to use that information as all my attemps still fails :P

Comment: Assuming `GetBuffer` doesn't return a reference, you'd have to create a separate variable to hold it in order to get the address of that variable and treat it like an array of one element.

Comment: As I understand it now. GetBuffer() returns a pointer to an object that doesnt really exists. By assigning it to another object. We can use that adress into the function; like so: ID3D11Buffer* uglyTemp = this->mVertexBuffer.GetBuffer();
 _deviceContext->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &uglyTemp, &stride, &offset);

Comment: Urgh.... Im just going to an Apply function or something, that just looks horrid